# adding locale on server

Tags: date, unix, locale

I am planning to use `strftime()`, however when I check my server regarding what's available locale, via `(locale -a)`, I only have this:

```
C
en_US.utf8 
POSIX
```

I badly need to have this **de_DE.utf8**, in order to turn my dates to German. How can I add additional locale? Is there any other better way?

Comment: You will need to tell us which OS is that

Comment: This is really system admininstration, not programming. Should be migrated.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to generate `de_DE.utf8` locale in your server.

The process is pretty straightforward. For example on Debian/Ubuntu distros, you can add/remove locales by issuing the following command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

You will be then presented with a list of available locales (basically all of them). Check/uncheck the one you like and click on OK. Good luck!

Comment: the only access I have is via SSH terminal, will this be possible?

Comment: Yes of course. Is your server Debian/Ubuntu? Or other flavors of Linux?

Comment: It will require him to be in the list of sudoers

Comment: It's Debian/Ubuntu, I have a root access it's just I'm not quite sure what will I do.

Comment: Login via ssh as root and type the command i have written without the `sudo` part, so `dpkg-reconfigure locales`

Comment: I've written [a short guide on how to install locales on Ubuntu](http://markushedlund.com/dev-tech/install-a-locale-on-ubuntu-11-10). Basically you run `locale-gen de_DE.utf8` as root.

Answer (score 31):

dpkg-reconfigure locales does nothing for me on a plain vanilla install of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, but locale-gen works like a charm:

```
sudo locale-gen de_DE.utf8
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Worked for me, too. I my case I had to restart apache after it,