# Number is not converting to indian money format in ms excel while exporting though laravel 5.4 maatwebsite package

Tags: php, excel, laravel-5, number-formatting, maatwebsite-excel

While exporting excel file through **laravel 5.4 maatwebsite** package numbers are not converting to **Indian money format** in windows **MS Excel**.

I've already set the column *format* as shown below code:

```
           `$sheet->setColumnFormat(array(
                'D' => '#,##0.00_-',
            ));`
```

Also tried this function- **PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat** but this function results in US money format.

Some example code:

`$sheet->setColumnFormat(array(
      'D' => \PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_NUMBER_COMMA_SEPARATED2
   ));`

```
       return \Excel::create($fileName, function($excel) use($reportQry){

          $excel->sheet('Report', function($sheet) use($reportQry,$excel){

              $sheet->setColumnFormat(array(
                  'C' => '#,##0.00_-',
                  'D' => \PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_NUMBER_COMMA_SEPARATED2
              ));
```

I need to convert the number to Indian number format in ms excel. Help for this will be highly appreciated.

Example images: [image: My output format image] and [image: Expected output image]

Comment: Perhaps show us what your input looks like, and what you expect the output to be.

Comment: @Sammitch added my output and expected output images. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

Wow that format hurts to read. Anywho:

```
var_dump(
    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_IN'),
    money_format('%.2n', $money),
    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'hi_IN'),
    money_format('%.2n', $money)
);
```

Output:

```
string(5) "en_IN"
string(15) "₹12,99,999.00"
string(5) "hi_IN"
string(15) "₹12,99,999.00"
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php

And if you're missing your preferred locale see: [adding locale on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9325024/adding-locale-on-server)

Also, be mindful of your charset. I used UTF8, and modern Excel should be able to handle it provided you set the encoding on the resulting file juuuuust right. Otherwise it might expect some legacy single-byte encoding for the `₹`.